# md5 php array value

Tags: php, md5

I need to hash a value using **md5** in a **PHP** array value,

```
'password' => array(        
   'value' => md5($form_data['password'])               
)
```

I tried with the above code but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Check if $form_data['password'] contains a value, because code is correct.

Comment: the value is there. but not md5ed.

Comment: show full code.

Comment: ok. Thanks for ur advice

Comment: `md5` hashing  is not recommended - md5 is broken

Comment: What is the value of $form_data['password']? And what is the result when you print the value in md5? Are you sure you check the correct variable for the md5? http://ideone.com/9lQMTe | Here you can see md5 works fine.

Answer (score 1):

check this code and working . i think your code is correct . so if you show your full array then we can understand which section problem. i define array as your code array and it is working fine

```
<?php
$array = array(
    'password' => array(
        'value' => '12456'
    ),
    'name' => array(
        'name' => 'Test Name'
    )
);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);

$md5_array = array(
    'password' => array(
        'value' => md5('12456')
    ),
    'name' => array(
        'name' => 'Test Name'
    )
);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($md5_array);
?>
```

then output before md5 :

```
Array
(
    [password] => Array
        (
            [value] => 12456
        )

    [name] => Array
        (
            [name] => Test Name
        )

)
```

after md5 :

```
Array
(
    [password] => Array
        (
            [value] => 6a9edcb7b63821802aa44d35d531c9fc
        )

    [name] => Array
        (
            [name] => Test Name
        )

)
```

for more information

http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php